# Resolving Maven effective dependencies for a specific point-in-time

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm writing a “compiler plugin”, and using Maven as build system. About one week ago, I had a (first) working version, and checked the code in. If I rebuild that version today, it doesn't work anymore, so my first suspicion is a change in the version of some (indirect?) dependency. Is there a Maven plugin, that can compare the effective dependencies of a POM between two different points in time (now, and “one week ago”)?

Expressed another way, is it possible to find out *when* a particular version became available in a Maven repo?

Comment: You specify versions for dependencies in the pom; they don't change. (?)

Comment: What kind of compiler plugin? What is the purpose? Apart from that if you have defined correctly the versions with releases they will never change. If you have used SNAPSHOT's that's a different story.

Comment: @BrianRoach they can if you depend on snapshot versions and even with release version, if the repo allows updates to release versions (which is possible with Nexus) then the transitive dependencies can change.

Comment: Guessing you won't be able to revert the dependency change, even if you wanted to, so you may as well just fix the code.  For future reference, make sure you set the `updatePolicy` in your repositories in the `settings.xml` to `never`.  That way at least you don't get your local copies changing beneath you until you choose to by using use the `-U` option.

Comment: @BrianRoach AFAIK Only if you specify exact version of everything. Even if I only specify exact version of *direct* dependencies (which I hadn't yet), but those had a "range" for their own dependencies, which are my indirect dependencies, then the "automatic Maven update" could pull newer versions, that just got released.

Comment: @NickHolt Good one; I'm just going through a Maven book right now, but hadn't read about that yet.

Comment: @khmarbaise It's an "Xtend compiler annotation plugin". As I stated above, I think they *can* change, if I don't nail down absolutely everything, including indirect dependencies, to exact versions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not really what I was looking for, but assuming there is no way to actually do it, the closest I found was this; Check out the date of the files in the local Maven repo:

```
cd <user-home>/.m2/repository

$ find . -type f -name "*.jar" -mtime -<how-many-days-ago-did-it-still-work>
```

And compare this to "mvn dependency:list"

In my case, it seems nothing relevant (apart from my own project jars) changed, so I can probably take Maven off the "suspect list".